# How to better format the JSON string generator with PHP json_encode()?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm saving data inside arrays with php's `json_encode()` function and then encoding them into json strings in order to save them into a single database field.

**This is what I've been doing:**

```
$fechaMensaje = $_POST['fechaMensaje'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$estadoMensaje = 'abierto';
$data['fecha'][] = $fechaMensaje;
$data['autor'][] = $userEmail;
$data['mensaje'][] = $mensaje;
$datosMensaje = json_encode($data);
```

**This does work, and it does creates a string like this:**

```
{
"fecha":["29-09-2016 11:12:51 AM"],
"autor":["demo@example.com"],
"mensaje":["lorem ipsum"]
}
```

**This is the array I've got when decoding the string:**

```
{
    ["fecha"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(22) "29-09-2016 11:12:51 AM" 
    } 
    ["autor"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(23) "demo@example.com" 
    } 
    ["mensaje"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" 
    } 
}
```

Now, my question is, how may I change the way I'm generating the array in the first place, to get this output instead? (having the three items in the same array, so when I do add more elements it's going to be more organized).

```
{
    ["0"]=> array(3) { 
        ['fecha']=> string(22) "29-09-2016 11:12:51 AM" 
        ['autor']=> string(23) "demo@example.com" 
        ['mensaje']=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ...
        ...
        ...       
    } 
}
```

Comment: `$data['fecha'][]` you don't want that `[]` on the end - that's assigning the data as an array not a string which accounts for the different structure.

Comment: How about `data[]['fecha'] = $fechaMensaje;` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
$obj['fecha'] = $fechaMensaje;
$obj['autor'] = $userEmail;
$obj['mensaje'] = $mensaje;

//insert obj to data array
$data[] = $obj;

// encoding to json 
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define another array, in the below case `$some_var`, to contain each array of data. Also remove `[]` on the end when assigning the values for `$data`.

```
$fechaMensaje = $_POST['fechaMensaje'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$estadoMensaje = 'abierto';
$data['fecha'] = $fechaMensaje;
$data['autor'] = $userEmail;
$data['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
$some_var[0] = $data;
$datosMensaje = json_encode($some_var);
```